# Pass extras to FragmentActivity its null

Tags: android, android-fragments

im sending data from one class to FragmentActivity like this:

```
public class OpenReportAction extends Action {
    private WorkActivity listener;

    public OpenReportAction(Activity listener) throws BadListenerException {
        if (!(listener instanceof WorkActivity)) {
            throw new BadListenerException("Listener must be context of WorkActivity");
        }
        this.listener = (WorkActivity) listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(List<Report> reports, Questions question) {
        Intent replyIntent = new Intent(listener, ReplyActivity.class);
        replyIntent.putExtra("id", listener.getWork().getID());
        replyIntent.putExtra("questions", question);
        replyIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("reports", (ArrayList<Report>) reports);
        listener.openReportOk(question);
        listener.startActivity(replyIntent);
    }

    public interface ReportCreatedCallback {
        void openReportOk(Questions question);

        void openReportError(WorkActionError cause);
    }
}
```

And i get the data like this:

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
            setContentView(R.layout.reply_activity);
            getData(getIntent());
            setFragment();
        }
 private void getData(Intent data) {
        ID = data.getLongExtra("id", 0);
        questions = data.getParcelableExtra("questions");
        reports = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("reports");
    }
```

But inside a FragmentActivity(ReplyActivity), the extras are allways null..How can i get it?

Comment: post your code where you read the extra in your activity

Comment: What's your `launchMode` flag? Try overriding `onNewIntent(Intent)` and see if it's been fired.

Comment: Its not been fired...:S

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "reports" extra is not a large object.
Large objects can't pass over an intent.
Hint: If it's the case you will see a log similar to that : "JAVA BINDER FAILURE"